# Why does trying to use $wpdb in a plugin function produce a syntax error?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins, qr-code

I am editing a QR code plugin, which essentially scans a code and sends you to its link. I am trying to add the functionality of writing the scanned contents into a custom WordPress MySQL table. I have loaded the core WP functions like this in the plugin file:

```
$path = preg_replace( '/wp-content.*$/', '', __DIR__ );
require_once( $path . 'wp-load.php' );
global $wpdb;
```

And here is the function to write to wpdb:

```
function write_scan($qrCodeMessage) {
    $wpdb->insert('scan', [ 'column' => 'tnx_id', 'field' => $qrCodeMessage ]
    );
}
```

The code produces the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'`

Reffering to the function 'write_scan'. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I tried to write to the database, but it seems like the php file doesn't support it.

Comment: You need to `global $wpdb;` in the function you're using it in, `write_scan`, before you  `$wpdb->insert`, so you'll have access to it. It's not available in function scope by default

Comment: Also, the array passed as the second argument should be `column => value` pairs.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, you should declare globals in the function itself. Otherwise they are not available. Also your use of the insert function is incorrect. You should give it an array with the keys being the column names and the values being the value you like to insert. Here is a working example:

```
function write_scan($qrCodeMessage) {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->insert('scan', ['tnx_id' => $qrCodeMessage ]);
}
```

Comment: It shows $wpdb as an 'unexpected identifier'.

Comment: Dude, ”unexpected identifier” is a javascript error. You are using php code. How you managed to get a Javascript error when using php is a mystery to me. It seems like you should temper your ambitions at the moment. Follow a couple of beginner tutorials on php and javascript and start an easier project to develop your skills.